# Replace folders and files with the most recent ones

Tags: python, shutil

I want to copy folders and files from a source directory to another destination directory. Each directory contains subfolders and many files already.
So far, I try the following code, inspired by a post in Stackoverflow:

```
import os
import shutil

root_src_dir = r'C:\....'
root_dst_dir  = r'C:\....'

for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
            # in case of the src and dst are the same file
            if os.path.samefile(src_file, dst_file):
                continue
            os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.copy2(src_file, dst_dir)
```

This code equates destination directory with source directory for identical folder and file names. This can replace the most recent folders and files in the destination, which is a disaster, while I want to keep the **newest ones** stay in both directories, when they had identical folder and file names.

Comment: If you care about the files you are transferring then use a pre-existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a program i wrote. It is a interactive one also with move and delete function along with copy. And filters data based on the extension.

```
import os
import shutil
from os.path import join
from time import perf_counter
print('Written By : SaGaR')
print('Applies operation on all the files with specified ext. to the destination path specified:')
scandir=input('Enter the path to scan(absolute or relative path):')
print(f'You entered :{scandir}')
choice = input('Enter operation to perform(move|copy|delete|list):').lower()
EXCLUDE=['Android','DCIM', 'documents', 'WhatsApp', 'MIUI','bluetooth'] #exclude some system folder on android . Add your one also. 
if choice == 'copy' or choice =='move':
    dest=input('Enter the destination path(absolute or relative path):')
    print(f'You entered :{dest}')
    EXCLUDE.append(dest)
DATA_TYPES=input('Enter Data types to filter(comma-seprated)(ex.- jpg,txt): ').split(',')
files2=[]
print('*'*5,'FINDING FILES')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scandir):
    for file in files:
        for typ in DATA_TYPES:
            if file.endswith(typ):
                a = join(root,file)
                print(root, end='')
                print('-->',file)
                files2.append(a)
    for directory in EXCLUDE:
        if directory in dirs:
            dirs.remove(directory)

            
def copy_move_files():
    start=perf_counter()
    print('-'*5, f'Trying To {choice.capitalize} Files')
    if not os.path.isdir(dest):
        print(f'{dest} does not exists')
        print(f'Creating {dest} directory')
        os.mkdir(dest)
    else:
        print(f'{dest} exists')
    for file in files2:
        fpath=os.path.join(dest,os.path.split(file)[-1])
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(fpath):
                if choice=='move':
                    
                    shutil.move(file,dest)
                    print(f'{file.split("/")[-1]} Moved Successfully')
                if choice=='copy':
                    shutil.copy(file,dest)
                    print(f'{file.split("/")[-1]} Copied Successfully')
            else:
                print(f'{file.split("/")[-1]} Already in destination folder')
        except shutil.SameFileError:
            print(f'{file.split("/")[-1].strip()} Already Exists in the destination directory. Add the Destination directory to EXCLUDE ')
    end = perf_counter() - start
    print(f'Operation took {end} second(s)')
      
            
def delete_files():
    print('-'*5, 'Trying To Delete Files')
    for file in files2:
        os.remove(file)
        print(f'{file} deleted')


if choice == 'copy' or choice=='move':
    copy_move_files()
elif choice == 'delete':
    delete_files()
else:
    print('No valid or "list" option detected\nOnly listing Files')
print('Exiting the program Now')
```

Comment: Whats the problem?what did you input? @k.ko3n

Comment: Written By : SaGaR    
Applies operation on all the files with specified ext. to the destination path specified:
Enter the path to scan(absolute or relative path): C:\Users\source\

You entered :C:\Users\source\

Enter operation to perform(move|copy|delete|list): copy
Enter the destination path(absolute or relative path): C:\Users\destination\
You entered :C:\Users\destination\

Enter Data types to filter(comma-seprated):  

***** FINDING FILES
C:\Users\.....

Comment: You didn't specified any extension to filter the data?

Comment: I did. It just show files in the source folder and stop there, without further copying them to destination folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using shutil.copytree and a my_copy function.

In my_copy there is an if statement that check which is the newest file.

```
import os
import shutil
def my_copy(src, dst):
    print(src)
    print(dst)
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        shutil.copy2(src,dst)
    else:   
        if os.path.getmtime(src) > os.path.getmtime(dst):
            shutil.copy2(src,dst)
    return True
    
def rec_copy():

    root_src_dir = r'C:\...'
    root_dst_dir  = r'C:\...'
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(root_dst_dir):
            print(os.path.exists(root_dst_dir))
            os.makedirs(root_dst_dir)
        print(os.path.exists(root_dst_dir)) 
        shutil.copytree(root_src_dir , root_dst_dir, copy_function=my_copy,  dirs_exist_ok=True)
            
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```